# Ajax appended content selectors not responding

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, append

I have a very peculiar problem where i'm get loading some content through ajax and then appending some more content to the newly added content

I'm going to try an explain the scenario.

First Ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
         url: href , 
         dataType: 'html',
         success: function(data) {
            var response = $(data).find('#content').html();
            $('#content').append(response)
           }
});
```

For simplicity sake lets assume that the content appended to the div content is

```
 <div id="wrap"></wrap>
```

2nd Ajax Call ( some api )

```
$.ajax({
     url: "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/sometumblr.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=someapikey",
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success: function(posts) {
      var postings = posts.response.posts,
          output = '';
          for (var i in postings) {
            var p = postings[i];
                output += '<div class="p"><div class="photo"><img src=' + p.photos[0].original_size.url + '/></div></div>';

        }
       $.when($('#wrap').append(output)).then( masonry());

                        }   
                    });
```

Masonry is a function that will be called after the output variable has been appended.

The issue here is, because the div wrap was appended to the DOM i'm not able to select it and then append the new content in the variable content. I'm aware of event delegation and jquery's .on() function but they all require an event to be passed. Unfortunately .prepend or .html() don't need event handlers so it would not work.

I've seen other nifty solutions using jquery's trigger and a custom event however in the masonry() function i need to pass the selector $('#wrap') as well so that solution would not suffice. Is the away to attach newly appended content to the DOM so that they can be used in the normal way.

i.e is append

```
   <div id="wrap"></wrap>
```

and  can use

```
 $('#wrap).html('some stuff')
```

Any pointers would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have 2 ajax calls that will be editing the same part of the DOM. So you will need to coordinate their changes.

1st ajax call can broadcast when it is finished. Do a `data` call in case it finishes first, and a `trigger` call in case it finishes second.

```
 $.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(data) {
    var response = $(data).find('#content').html();
    $('#content').append(response)
                 .data('done-appending', true); // mark as ready
    $(document).trigger('content-appended');    // trigger custom event
  }
});
```

2nd ajax call checks to see if the coast is clear by looking for the `data` you set, and if not it will wait for the custom event.

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(posts) {
    var postings = posts.response.posts,
        output = '';
    ...
    // call this function when everything is ready and #wrap is in the DOM:
    var appendOutput = function () {
      $('#wrap').append(output);
      masonry();
    };
    if($('#content').data('done-appending')) {
      // ready to proceed
      appendOutput();
    }
    else {
      // need to wait for the custom event to fire
      $(document).one('content-appended', appendOutput);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. before posting the question i actually set a timeout for the second ajax function to be called 30 seconds after the first ajax call to make sure that blog-wrap is appended before inserting new content into it. The solution i'm looking for is a way to use $('#wrap') after it has been inserted in the DOM through ajax

Comment: I may not be understanding the problem then. Once an element is in the DOM, via ajax callback or otherwise, you should be able to access it using jquery selectors, as in $("#wrap"). Perhaps the issue is with masonry, whatever it is doing before you make the `masonry()` call itself.

Comment: You have probably already seen this, but here's how to [initialize masonry with jquery](http://masonry.desandro.com/#initialize-with-jquery)